# How to share data between devices?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, parse-platform

Hello i want to share lists in my app between different devices. I want that person a can invite persob b to his list. Now person a and person b can read and modify the list.

The list is only visible for the invited pesons (person a and b). But every person who has donwloaded the app can create his own list and
invite persons.

But how can i implement the invitation function that person a can invite person b?

Do you have an idea how to implement the invitation and share functionallity or does anybody have a good tutorial?

Any suggestions are very welcome.

Comment: If you want complete tutorials, Parse offers diverse tutorials (https://parse.com/tutorials), it's definitely worth checking out

Answer (score 0):

This can be done. With Parse. Read through the documentation on Parse's website. Once you tinker with a few things and see how it all works you'll come up with a clever solution. Use google as well if you're ever stuck on anything. It's all trial and error.

Parse iOS Guide
https://parse.com/docs/ios_guide#top/iOS